# How to find out If Magento MySQL is hosted on AWS RDS

Tags: magento-1.9, database, aws

How do I find out if my Magento Instance's Database is being hosted on RDS? I see a RDS instance on AWS, but am not sure how I test without actually stopping the RDS. Wondering if there's a more elegant way to determine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you could check the database connection string in your `app/etc/local.xml` file. You might find it in the xml structure inside `config > global > resources > default_setup > connection > host`. The hostname might be inside a CDATA structure and look like `myrdsinstancename.a098420934.ap-zone.rds.amazonaws.com`.

Then, check in AWS RDS > Instances > Click on your instance. Search for an attribute called "Endpoint". If this is the same as the one listed in the `local.xml` file above, then you have found your db instance.